# I am unable to upload App Icon file in Facebook Console

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to upload the App Icon.

The file that i am uploading is as per the explained criteria. Its a PNG file and of size 1024*1024 pixels size. I have tried multiple times to upload the file.

It is not showing any error yet i see no "save" button after i choose a file.

Here is how it looks after i choose a file. There are no errors, no file name and no save button on the dialog.

[image]

**Update:**

> It was **Facebook's Bug** which is resolved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its already reported as a bug in facebook developer support. Your are not the only one hving that problem. If you see in the browser console, when you choose a file it gives a CORS problem

Comment: Yes turned out, it was Facebook's bug. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug... Your developer account is less than 24 hours? Because facebook not able to send an picture if your account was created less than 24 hours ago.

Please wait these time and try again.

Comment: No, my developer's account is around 5 years old. Anyways, it is resolved now. It was Facebook's bug.  Thanks